# Reconfigure Keycloak 21 to keep logs for more than one day

Tags: logging, jboss, keycloak, quarkus

Dears,

I would like to reconfigure Keycloak 21 to keep logs for more than one day. I have tried to do it via quarkus.properties but no success. Seems like Keycloak is not accepting that configuration without any error.

Via following thread https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/24957 I have learned possibility to use quarkus.properties file.

I have configured quarkus.properties for my Keycloak installation according to documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file-file-logging.

Basically I would like to reconfigure Keycloak 21 to keep logs for more than one day. I can use any possible way. It don't have to be via quarkus.properties.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.